# Сомневаюсь по поводу запятых

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте, помогите, пожалуйста. Я всё сомневаюсь, не нужна ли в этом предложении запятая?

Официально данный результат зарегистрирован как рекорд Челябинской области в классической тяге в категории 120+ по версии IPF.

Answer (score 5):

*Официально данный результат зарегистрирован как рекорд Челябинской области в классической тяге в категории 120+ по версии IPF.*

Запятая в этом предложении **не нужна**, поскольку здесь **нет сравнительного оборота.** В предложении имеется в виду, *что результат зарегистрирован в качестве рекорда.* В этом и подобных ему случаях запятая перед *как* не ставится.

Comment: А между "в категории 120+ по версии IPF" почему не ставится, не знаете?

Answer (score 3):

Официально данный результат зарегистрирован как рекорд Челябинской области в классической тяге **в категории 120+ по версии IPF.**

Нет запятой "в категории 120+ по версии IPF"; это **неоднородные** обстоятельства,   причем второе обстоятельство **не является уточняющим**: это по смыслу основная информация, а не дополнительная, — результат зарегистрирован именно по этой версии.

(Версия IPF — таблица разрядных нормативов.)